# Can you store Visual Studio 2013 project template in source control?

Tags: templates, visual-studio-2013, tfs

We've created a custom project template in visual studio 2013 for the whole team to use, as the vast majority of our projects have the same styling/branding/main pages etc.

We've managed to export this template and distributed it around the team so everyone has it available in their list of installed templates when they begin a new project.

What we're now wondering is whether there is any method for storing the template itself in source control (we use TFS generally but open to alternatives) so that the template can evolve over time and then a team member can just get the most up to date version of the template down prior to beginning a new project?

Any suggestions appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's nothing stopping you from exporting the process template XML and putting it in source control. However, you still have to manually upload the process template and/or apply template changes.

You can certainly use the build system to automate the process of uploading process templates, but the XAML build system in TFS 2013 makes that prospect unappealing.